# assign variable with find option

Tags: find

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s failglob
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' -printf 'x' | wc -c
```

I need to assign the numeric result of the `find` command to a variable. For example:

```
a=find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' -printf 'x' | wc -c.
```

How can I assign a variable for the result of the `find` function?

Comment: Your `shopt` commands are not necessary here since you're not using the shell to assemble the file list. (The command argument `'*[0-9][0-9]o'` obeys the same *rules* as a shell glob, but is actually processed internally by `find`, which knows how to handle empty matches).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(...)` for that:

```
a=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' -printf 'x' | wc -c) ; echo "$a"
```

Another option is to use backticks:

```
a=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' -printf 'x' | wc -c` ; echo "$a"
```

Note that if you use nested backticks, you will need to escape them with backslashes.

Here's more information on command substitution: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst

Comment: `a=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' | wc -l)`

Comment: @A.P. , @A.B. the reason for using `-printf 'x' | wc -c` for file counting is that it makes it safe for the (rare - but legal) case of filenames that contain newline characters

Comment: @steeldriver Oh I see. You are right. Also, counting bytes with  `wc -c` seems to be faster. Thanks, updated the answer.